# Unexpected result when trying to get ip from HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, ip, jax-rs, postman

I'm trying to get the IP from HttpServletRequest when someone does a POST request to my REST-interface (I'm using jax-rs). Here's the method I'm using to get the IP (found in another question here on StackOverflow):

```
public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    }
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
}
```

The result received when making a request (in this case from PostMan) is this String: `fe80:0:0:0:89a0:94d3:58a:a4e3%24`. For me this is unexpected. I need to understand how to get a proper IP.

As understood from the comments, what I'm getting is the ipv6 adress, what I need to is the ipv4 adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an IPV6 address with a $ at the end.   I don't know which part of the function you are getting this from.

The traditional IPV4 address is part of this.  Different parts of the function may be returning different versions of IP.   I don't know, but I would put some traces in it to find out what is happening.  You can get quite a bit of confusion if you don't know what is coming from where.

The GetRemoteAddress function is the IP address directly connected to the servlet, but, of course, it could have gone through proxies etc.

Depends really what you are using the IP address for.   I would argue it is worth building IPV6 functionality into the system for future proofing even if that future is some way down the track.

Comment: I checked, and it's coming from request.getRemoteAddr().

Comment: That has an interesting way of either giving IPV4 addresses or IPV6 addresses depending upon what entry there is in the DNS for the domain being used to access the server.   I am still, however, mystified as to the dollar sign.  It happens to be that I was using the same function with tomcat a couple of days ago and I don't get the dollar at the end.

Comment: Someone else wrote a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118829/why-request-getremoteaddr-returns-ipv4-or-ipv6-depending-on-context-post-quer

Comment: There is a way of mapping V4 onto V6 which I think is accurately described here (but might not be).  http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding-2.htm   However, it looks like this is not one of those addresses and only exists as V6.  Still I would personally code for V6 anyway.  It will happen some day (as did the millennium and I did a lot of coding for that in 1998)